# Sort CSV file alphabetically in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv, sorting

```
self.students.includes(:events).each do |student|
    row = []
    row.push student.first_name
    row.push student.last_name
    row.push student.title
    row.push student.id
    csv << row
end
```

As of now, each user's data is inputted into the CSV file one row at a time using the row array. Afterward, the loop moves on to the next user.

However, the problem is that the users aren't being inputted alphabetically. I would normally use the following code to sort an array alphabetically.

```
row.sort_by! {|student| [student.last_name, student.firstname]}
```

But seeing how this would be ineffective since only one row would be sorted at a time I'm looking for another solution. What is another way to sort the data going into the CSV alphabetically? From what I've seen, it's unlikely that I would be able to sort the CSV file in the loop but I'm unsure of how to do so outside of the loop. So, if you have any suggestions please share.

Comment: What is the result of `self.students.includes(:events)`. I would expect an Enumerable, then your expection of _since only one row would be sorted at a time_ would be wrong. You could try `self.students.includes(:events).sort_by{|student| [student.last_name, student.firstname]}.each...`

Comment: Thanks so much, this solution did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

What about sorting students first?

```
self.students
.includes(:events)
.sort_by { |s| [s.last_name, s.firstname] }
.each do |student|
    csv << [
      student.first_name,
      student.last_name,
      student.title,
      student.id,
    ]
end
```

---

However from what I see `self.students` is probably `ActiveRecord` query, so then, why not sort it using DB?

```
self.students
.includes(:events)
.order(last_name: :asc, first_name: :asc)
.each do |student|
    csv << [
      student.first_name,
      student.last_name,
      student.title,
      student.id,
    ]
end
```

---

But that is still wrong, as you can have too much results to fit into memory at once, so instead you should use `#find_each` which will load data in batches:

```
self.students
.includes(:events)
.order(last_name: :asc, first_name: :asc)
.find_each do |student|
    csv << [
      student.first_name,
      student.last_name,
      student.title,
      student.id,
    ]
end
```

---

But why not improve it more, as you do not need rest of fields it is better to select only what you need, so:

```
self.students
.includes(:events)
.order(last_name: :asc, first_name: :asc)
.select(:first_name, :last_name, :title, :id)
.find_each do |student|
    csv << [
      student.first_name,
      student.last_name,
      student.title,
      student.id,
    ]
end
```